# Jasper Sub Reports Not Being Displayed

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report
Calling 2 different sub reports , twice , with different parameters each time

Issues is the display is not coming correctly.
LETTEROFACK_TRANSF_LTR , is not coming at all

```
<jasperReport name="LETTEROFACK" columnCount="1" printOrder="Vertical" orientation="Portrait" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="484" columnSpacing="0" leftMargin="64" rightMargin="64" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" whenNoDataType="NoPages" isTitleNewPage="false"          isSummaryNewPage="true">

    <queryString><![CDATA[......]]></queryString>

    <field name="GRP_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="DATE_VALUE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PERSON_ID_AT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PERSON_ID_AF" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_PRIM_SALUTATION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_HF_GREETING" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_FIRST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_MIDDLE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_LAST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_PRIMARY_ORG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_ADDRESS1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_PRIM_SALUTATION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_HF_GREETING" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_FIRST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_MIDDLE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_LAST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_PRIMARY_ORG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_ADDRESS1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_PRIMARY_LOGIN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AT_NOMINEE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="AF_NOMINEE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="FUND_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TRANSFER_AMT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TRANSFER_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TRANSFER_DATE1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <detail>
            <band height="630"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <break>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="129"
                        width="484"
                        height="0"
                        key="element-1"/>
                </break>
                <subreport  isUsingCache="true">
                    <reportElement
                        x="10"
                        y="156"
                        width="199"
                        height="77"
                        key="subreport-2"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <subreportParameter  name="FUND_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{FUND_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFER_DATE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRANSFER_DATE1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="REPORT_BASE_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}+"LETTEROFACK_SUB.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <break>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="280"
                        width="484"
                        height="0"
                        key="element-2"/>
                </break>
                <break>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="452"
                        width="484"
                        height="0"
                        key="element-3"/>
                </break>
                <subreport  isUsingCache="true">
                    <reportElement
                        x="12"
                        y="478"
                        width="199"
                        height="73"
                        key="subreport-4"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <subreportParameter  name="FUND_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{FUND_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFER_DATE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRANSFER_DATE1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="REPORT_BASE_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}+"LETTEROFACK_SUB.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport  isUsingCache="true">
                    <reportElement
                        x="10"
                        y="14"
                        width="199"
                        height="71"
                        key="subreport-1"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <subreportParameter  name="DATE_VALUE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATE_VALUE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="PRIM_SALUTATION">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_PRIM_SALUTATION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="HF_GREETING">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_HF_GREETING}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="FIRST_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_FIRST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="MIDDLE_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_MIDDLE_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="LAST_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_LAST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="PRIMARY_ORG">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_PRIMARY_ORG}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="ADDRESS1">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_ADDRESS1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="NOMINEE_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_NOMINEE_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFERRED_FROM">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_FIRST_NAME}+($F{AT_MIDDLE_NAME} != null ? " "+$F{AT_MIDDLE_NAME}:"")+" "+$F{AT_LAST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFERRED_TO">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_FIRST_NAME}+($F{AF_MIDDLE_NAME} != null ? " "+$F{AF_MIDDLE_NAME}:"")+" "+$F{AF_LAST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="FUND_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{FUND_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFER_AMT">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRANSFER_AMT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="REPORT_BASE_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}+"LETTEROFACK_TRANSF_LTR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport  isUsingCache="true">
                    <reportElement
                        x="11"
                        y="311"
                        width="199"
                        height="104"
                        key="subreport-3"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <subreportParameter  name="DATE_VALUE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATE_VALUE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="PRIM_SALUTATION">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_PRIM_SALUTATION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="HF_GREETING">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_HF_GREETING}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="FIRST_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_FIRST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="MIDDLE_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_MIDDLE_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="LAST_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_LAST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="PRIMARY_ORG">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_PRIMARY_ORG}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="ADDRESS1">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_ADDRESS1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="NOMINEE_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_NOMINEE_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFERRED_FROM">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AF_FIRST_NAME}+($F{AF_MIDDLE_NAME} != null ? " "+$F{AF_MIDDLE_NAME}:"")+" "+$F{AF_LAST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFERRED_TO">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{AT_FIRST_NAME}+($F{AT_MIDDLE_NAME} != null ? " "+$F{AT_MIDDLE_NAME}:"")+" "+$F{AT_LAST_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="FUND_NAME">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{FUND_NAME}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="TRANSFER_AMT">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRANSFER_AMT}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter  name="REPORT_BASE_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}+"LETTEROFACK_TRANSF_LTR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

One Sub Report is  ( the one not being displayed )

```
<jasperReport name="" columnCount="1" printOrder="Vertical" orientation="Portrait" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="484" columnSpacing="0" leftMargin="64" rightMargin="64" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" whenNoDataType="NoPages" isTitleNewPage="false" isSummaryNewPage="false">
    <parameter name="REPORT_BASE_DIR" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="DATE_VALUE" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="PRIM_SALUTATION" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="HF_GREETING" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="FIRST_NAME" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="MIDDLE_NAME" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="LAST_NAME" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="PRIMARY_ORG" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ADDRESS1" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ADDRESS2" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ADDRESS3" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ADDRESS4" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CITY" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="STATE" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ZIP_CODE" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CITY_STATE_ZIPCODE" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="NOMINEE_NAME" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TRANSFERRED_FROM" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TRANSFERRED_TO" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="FUND_NAME" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="TRANSFER_AMT" isForPrompting="true" class="java.lang.String"/>

        <background>
            <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
            <band height="96"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()%2==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
            </band>
        </pageHeader>
        <columnHeader>
            <band height="0"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="630"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Report" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="53"
                        width="168"
                        height="14"
                        forecolor="#000000"
                        backcolor="#FFFFFF"
                        key="Date-1"/>
                    <box>                   <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
</box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="BentonSans Book" pdfFontName="font.otf" size="10" isBold="false" isPdfEmbedded ="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="83"
                        width="483"
                        height="14"
                        key="Salutation1-1"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($P{PRIM_SALUTATION} != null ? $P{PRIM_SALUTATION}.concat($P{PRIM_SALUTATION}.lastIndexOf('.') != -1 ? " " : ". ") : "")+$P{FIRST_NAME}+($P{MIDDLE_NAME} != null ? " "+$P{MIDDLE_NAME}:"")+" "+$P{LAST_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="97"
                        width="294"
                        height="14"
                        key="textField-1"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{PRIMARY_ORG}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="111"
                        width="294"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-1"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{ADDRESS1} == null ? "" : $P{ADDRESS1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="125"
                        width="294"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add2-1"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{ADDRESS2} == null ? "" : $P{ADDRESS2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="139"
                        width="294"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add3-1"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{ADDRESS3} == null ? "" : $P{ADDRESS3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="153"
                        width="294"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add4-1"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{ADDRESS4} == null ? "" : $P{ADDRESS4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="225"
                        width="462"
                        height="14"
                        key="Greeting-1"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Dear "+($P{HF_GREETING}.equalsIgnoreCase( "null" )?($P{FIRST_NAME}.equalsIgnoreCase( "null" )?"":$P{FIRST_NAME}):$P{HF_GREETING})+":"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="424"
                        width="90"
                        height="14"
                        key="staticText-2"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sincerely,]]></text>
                </staticText>

                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="474"
                        width="110"
                        height="14"
                        key="staticText-4"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="167"
                        width="294"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add4-2"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($P{CITY} == null ? "" : $P{CITY}+ ", ").concat($P{STATE} == null ? "" : $P{STATE}+" ").concat($P{ZIP_CODE} == null ? "" : $P{ZIP_CODE})]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="5"
                        y="181"
                        width="42"
                        height="15"
                        key="staticText-15"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="4"
                        y="210"
                        width="42"
                        height="15"
                        key="staticText-16"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="4"
                        y="239"
                        width="42"
                        height="10"
                        key="staticText-17"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="4"
                        y="409"
                        width="42"
                        height="15"
                        key="staticText-20"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="4"
                        y="67"
                        width="42"
                        height="15"
                        key="staticText-21"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="372"
                        width="475"
                        height="50"
                        key="textField-9"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[text text text]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="196"
                        width="483"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-2"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Account Name: "+$P{NOMINEE_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="248"
                        width="483"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-3"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[We confirm the following:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="261"
                        width="483"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-4"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Transferred From :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="0"
                        y="315"
                        width="482"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-5"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Transferred To  :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="55"
                        y="274"
                        width="89"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-6"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Registered Holder]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="55"
                        y="287"
                        width="89"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-7"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fund]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="55"
                        y="300"
                        width="89"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-8"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="148"
                        y="274"
                        width="331"
                        height="12"
                        key="Add1-9"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{TRANSFERRED_FROM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="148"
                        y="287"
                        width="331"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-10"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fund , Ltd]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="148"
                        y="301"
                        width="331"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-11"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{DATE_VALUE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="56"
                        y="330"
                        width="89"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-12"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Registered Holder]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="149"
                        y="330"
                        width="331"
                        height="12"
                        key="Add1-13"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{TRANSFERRED_TO}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="149"
                        y="343"
                        width="331"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-14"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fund , Ltd]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="56"
                        y="343"
                        width="89"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-15"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fund]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement
                        x="56"
                        y="356"
                        width="89"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-16"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="149"
                        y="357"
                        width="331"
                        height="14"
                        key="Add1-17"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font .../>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{DATE_VALUE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Will appreciate help on debugging same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing from main report the report connection `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}`as datasource to the subreport .

This means that in subreport we expect a **query** to show data in **detail band** (I can not find this query in subreport).

**Since you like to:** *(discovered by comments)*

*Pass **all** data as parameters, you don't want to do any query in subreport*,

**The solution is:**

In subreport, do **not** put the `textField`'s in the **detail band** (our datasource is with 0 record the detail band will not be displayed), use another band as for example `title` band.

> The detail band in jasper report is repeated for every record in the datasource, you have no records so it will not be repeated/displayed.

Furthermore you need to set the attribute `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` on the subreports `jasperReport` tag, otherwise it will  be blank (since we have **no data**, 0 records and default is `noPages`). For additional information see [WhenNoDataTypeEnum](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/WhenNoDataTypeEnum.html)

**Other notes:**

You should also be more careful about indicating `pageHeight` and `margins` on your reports. A sub report with `pageHeight="792"` can **not fit** in a "main" report with `pageHeight="792"` and `topMargin="20"`, hence **792 > 772**

**Edit**: added band definition since OP had some comments on this (the edit is copied from [Understanding-iReport-Elements](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Using-Jasper-Reports-Part-1--(Understanding-iReport-Elements))):

> **Title**  It is the very first band of the report and is printed only
>   once . This area is used to print title of the document and the
>   information that is needed only once in whole iReport.
>
> **Page Header**  This is like a title per page and printed on each page of
>   the report . This is used to setup header information on the page .
>
> **Column Header**  Like page header this band prints on each page,but it
>   prints only if there is a detail band on that page.
>
> **Detail**  This is the most usefull and tricky band of all , This band is
>   repeatedly prints for each row in the data source. In the List of
>   emp_detail report, it is printed for each emp_detail.
>
> **Column Footer**   Is printed on each page if there is a detail band on
>   that page. If the Floating column footer in report Properties is
>   checked, then the column footer will be shown just below the last data
>   of the column, otherwise it will be shown at the bottom of the page
>   (above the page footer).
>
> **Page Footer**   This area is usefull place to insert page numbers. If
>   Last Page Footer is set thab this page prints on each page except the
>   last page,and If  Last Page Footer is not set, then it is printed on
>   the last page also.
>
> **Last Page Footer**  This prints at the end of the document , all
>   finishing text and information can be printed in this area.
>
> **Summary**  This is used to conclude the document and it prints only once
>   at the end of the report.
>
> **Background** This portion is used to set a background image for the
>   document , it is a good place to insert a watermark image for report
>   pages

Comment: Thanks peter for your response , i removed $P{DATASOURCE} still it didnt work ... my case is as #1 , i didnt understand .... You should not put the textField's in the detail band (our datasource is with 0 record the detail band will not be displayed), use another band as title.. .can you pls explain with example .... also for  attribute whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" on the jasperReport tag ... are you talking of sub-report ??

Comment: First its important to understand that jasper report will repeat what  you have in detail band as many times as you have records in your datasource. Since you have no records (no query --> no records) it will never be repeated. Thats why you need to put your fields in another band example the <title> band (it will  always exits) and you need to tell jasper report to executed the sub report even if there is no data that you do with whenNoDataType attribute. (I will also edit answer to clarify)

Comment: It is not about removing the datasource, in your case its about using the correct band since we have no  records in datasource,  just try to in xml edit the tag <detail></detail> to <title></title> and maybe you willsee the difference.

Comment: I have edit the answer so you see different band structure in jasper report